# inherit from a has-a relationship

Tags: c++

I vaguely remember looking at an example in C++ were a class has a member object in it and the first exposed a function that belongs to second as if it where its own.

Here is an example to explain what I mean:

```
class Engine{
   int cylinders;
public:
/* ... */
   int getCylindersCount() { return this->cylinders;}
};

class Car {
   Engine engine;
public:
   /* define getCylindersCount() as if it were a function in class Car */
   /* something like Car::getCylindersCount is engine.getCylindersCount(); */
};
```

So basically users of class Car can do this:

```
Car mytoyota;
mytoyota.getCylindersCount();
```

Now, I am not talking about a simple wrapper like:

```
class Car {
   Engine engine;
public:
   int getCylindersCount() { return engine.getCylindersCount();}
};
```

Can you help me remember what the syntax is to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `int getCylindersCount() { return engine.getCylindersCount();}`?

Comment: @DimChtz nothing wrong with it. Just wondering if my memory is right.

As I mentioned and if my memory serves me right, I do remember there was something readily available in C++ that can do this for you, why not use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing.

But the syntax you're referring to does exist: It's a deprecated way to change access qualifiers of inherited member functions:

```
class A
{
  public:
    void foo() {}
};

class B : A
{
  public:
    A::foo; // Otherwise A::foo() would be private.
    // A non-deprecated way to do the same thing:
    // using A::foo;
};
```